# I am unable to submit my form after adding a javascript file to the html

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation, form-submit

[The output when submitted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyQwa.png) I created a signup page, but I am unable to submit the form after it has been filled and validated to be correct by the .js file attached to it. Also, I am unable to make the error message that will be displayed when there is a wrong filling on the form disappear when it has been corrected, unless the form is submitted (i.e the success mark only shows when the submit button is clicked)

I created a page that will accept inputs and I used javascript to validate the form before it will be submitted. But after the javascript validates the form, it refuses to submit it to the action attached to the form. I also tried to make the error message which I set using the javascript to disappear when the correct data has been filled, but I was unable to do that.

If I can possibly get a date validator to be added to the .js file to check if the date is a valid date. Tried adding it but to no avail.

```js
const form = document.getElementById('form');
const firstname = document.getElementById('firstname');
const lastname = document.getElementById('lastname');
const email = document.getElementById('email');
const dob = document.getElementById('dob');
const phone = document.getElementById('phone');
const username = document.getElementById('username');
const password = document.getElementById('password');
const confpassword = document.getElementById('confpassword');

form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
e.preventDefault();

checkInputs();
});

function checkInputs(){
//to get values from inputs
const firstnameValue = firstname.value.trim();
const lastnameValue = lastname.value.trim();
const emailValue = email.value.trim();
const dobValue = dob.value.trim();
const phoneValue = phone.value.trim();
const usernameValue = username.value.trim();
const passwordValue = password.value.trim();
const confpasswordValue = confpassword.value.trim();

if(firstnameValue === '') {
setErrorFor(firstname, 'Please enter your name');
} else {
setSuccessFor(firstname);
}

if(lastnameValue === '') {
setErrorFor(lastname, 'Please enter your name');
} else {
setSuccessFor(lastname);
}

if (dobValue === '') {
setErrorFor(dob, 'Please enter your date of birth');
// } else if (!isValidDate(dobValue)) {
// setErrorFor(dob, 'Please enter a valid date in the format YYYY-MM-DD');
// } else if (isAgeLessThan16(dobValue)) {
// setErrorFor(dob, 'You must be 16 years or older');
} else {
setSuccessFor(dob);
}

if(phoneValue === '') {
setErrorFor(phone, 'Please enter your phone number');
} else if(phoneValue.length < 11) {
setErrorFor(phone, 'Please enter your 11 digits number');
}else {
setSuccessFor(phone);
}

if(usernameValue === '') {
setErrorFor(username, 'Please choose a username');
} else {
setSuccessFor(username);
}

if(passwordValue === '') {
setErrorFor(password, 'Please enter a strong password');
} else if(passwordValue.length < 8) {
setErrorFor(password, 'Your Password must be at least 8 characters');
// } else if(!isStrong(passwordValue)) {
// setErrorFor(password, 'Include letters(Upper and lower cases), numbers and special characters');
} else {
setSuccessFor(password);
}

if (confpasswordValue === '') {
setErrorFor(confpassword, 'Please enter your password');
} else if(confpasswordValue !== passwordValue){
setErrorFor(confpassword, 'Password not match!');
} else {
setSuccessFor(confpassword);
}

if(emailValue === '') {
setErrorFor(email, 'Please fill in your Email address');
} else if(!isEmail(emailValue)) {
setErrorFor(email, 'Please enter a valid Email address');
} else{
setSuccessFor(email);
}

}

function setErrorFor(input, message) {
const formControl = input.parentElement; // .input-part
const small = formControl.querySelector('small');

//add error message inside small
small.innerText = message;

//add form control class
formControl.className = 'input-part error';
return false;
}

function setSuccessFor(input) {
formControl = input.parentElement;
formControl.className = 'input-part success';
return true;
}

function isEmail(email) {
    return /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/.test(email);
}
```

```css
*{
font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
min-height: 100vh;
margin: auto;
padding: 20px;
background-color: white;
background-size: cover;
}

.logo {
position: absolute;
transform: translateY(-500px);
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
width: 300px;
max-width: 300px;
}

.logo img {
width: 100%;
}

.signup {
overflow: hidden;
background-color: whitesmoke;
border-radius: 5px;
box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(172, 84, 84, 0.775);
width: 500px;
max-width: 100%;
margin-top: 200px;
}

.signup a {
text-decoration: none;
color: black;
}

.signup a:hover {
text-decoration: underline;
}

.header {
background-color: antiquewhite;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 25px;
font-weight: bold;
padding: 20px 40px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;
}

.form {
padding: 30px 40px;
}

.input-part {
margin-bottom: 10px;
padding-bottom: 20px;
position: relative;
}


.input-part label {
display: inline-block;
margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.input-part input {
border: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
display: block;
width: 100%;
padding: 10px;
font-size: 15px;
font-family: inherit;
background: transparent;
outline: none;
border-radius: 7px;
}

.input-part.success input {
border-color: #2fcd71;
}

.input-part.success i.fa-check-circle {
visibility: visible;
color: #2fcd71;
}

.input-part.error input {
border-color: red;
animation: shake 0.14s 3;
}

.input-part.error i.fa-exclamation-circle {
visibility: visible;
color: red;
animation: shake 0.14s 3;
}

.input-part.error small {
visibility: visible;
color: red;
animation: shake 0.14s 3;
}

@keyframes shake {
0%,100% {translate: 0;}
25% {translate: 8px 0;}
75% {translate: -8px 0;}
}

.btn {
width: 100%;
margin: 25x auto;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
background-color: rgb(95, 95, 223);
color: white;
font-size: 18px;
font-weight: bold;
letter-spacing: 2px;
text-transform: uppercase;
border: none;
border-radius: 5px;
padding: 15px 16px;
cursor: pointer;
outline: none;
}

.btn:active {
transform: scale(95%);
}

.input-part i {
visibility: hidden;
position: absolute;
top: 35px;
right: 10px;
}

.input-part small {
visibility: hidden;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
}

.login {
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
gap: 10px;
margin-bottom: 25px;
margin-top: -5px;
font-size: 13px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- removed -->
<body>

<div class="logo">
<a href="../index.html"><img src="../images/icons/_logo.png" alt=""></a>
</div>

<div class="signup">
<div class="header">signup</div>

<form action="signup.php" class="form" id="form" method="post">

<div class="input-part ">
<label for="firstname">First Name</label>
<input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" placeholder="e.g Yusuf">
<i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
<i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
<small>Error</small>
</div>
<div class="input-part">
<label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
<input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" placeholder="e.g Olanrewaju">
<i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
<i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
<small>Error</small>
</div>
<div class="input-part">
<label for="email">Email Address</label>
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="mail@email.com">
<i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
<i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
<small>Error</small>
</div>
<div class="input-part">
<label for="dob">Birthday</label>
<input type="text" maxlength="10" id="dob" name="dob" placeholder="Enter your Birthday (YYYY/MM/DD)">
<i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
<i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
<small id="dobError">Error</small>

<script defer src="date.js"></script>

</div>
<div class="input-part">
<label for="phone">Phone Number</label>
<input type="text" id="phone" maxlength="11" name="phone" placeholder="Enter Phone Number" oninput="validateNumericInput(this)">
<i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
<i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
<small>Error</small>

<script defer src="maxlenght.js"></script>
<script defer src="phone.js"></script>

</div>
<div class="input-part">
<label for="username">Username</label>
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Choose a Username">
<i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
<i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
<small>Error</small>
</div>
<div class="input-part">
<label for="password">Password</label>
<input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Enter a strong Password" oninput="checkPasswordStrength(this)">
<i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
<i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
<small id="passwordStrength">Error</small>
</div>
<div class="input-part">
<label for="confpassword">Confirm Password</label>
<input type="password" name="confpassword" id="confpassword" placeholder="Re-enter Password">
<i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
<i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
<small>Error</small>
</div>

<button class="btn" type="submit" >Signup</button>

</form>

<div class="login">
 <span>Have an account?</span> <a href="../index.html">Login</a>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's impossible to debug without seeing the code

Comment: @Phix I have added the codes

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to use the build in input validation. If a form field is tested invalid it will the the class name `invalid`. And when you stat to type again the class name will be removed when the field is valid.

And then let the form submit in the end. It will not submit as long as the required fields are not valid.

```js
document.forms.form01.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('submit');
});

document.forms.form01.addEventListener('invalid', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.target.value = e.target.value.trim();
  if (!e.target.validity.valid) {
    e.target.classList.add('invalid');
  }
}, true);

document.forms.form01.addEventListener('input', e => {
  if (e.target.name == 'password') {
    e.target.form.confpassword.pattern = e.target.value;
  }
  if (e.target.validity.valid) {
    e.target.classList.remove('invalid');
  }
}, true);
```

```css
* {
  font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: white;
  background-size: cover;
}

.logo {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateY(-500px);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 300px;
  max-width: 300px;
}

.logo img {
  width: 100%;
}

.signup {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(172, 84, 84, 0.775);
  width: 500px;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.signup a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.signup a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.header {
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 20px 40px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;
}

.form {
  padding: 30px 40px;
}

.input-part {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.input-part label {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.input-part input {
  border: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: inherit;
  background: transparent;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 7px;
}

input:valid {
  border-color: #2fcd71;
}

.input-part.success i.fa-check-circle {
  visibility: visible;
  color: #2fcd71;
}

input.invalid {
  border-color: red;
  animation: shake 0.14s 3;
}

.input-part.error i.fa-exclamation-circle {
  visibility: visible;
  color: red;
  animation: shake 0.14s 3;
}

input.invalid~small {
  visibility: visible;
  color: red;
  animation: shake 0.14s 3;
}

@keyframes shake {
  0%,
  100% {
    translate: 0;
  }
  25% {
    translate: 8px 0;
  }
  75% {
    translate: -8px 0;
  }
}

.btn {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 25x auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: rgb(95, 95, 223);
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 15px 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}

.btn:active {
  transform: scale(95%);
}

.input-part i {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 35px;
  right: 10px;
}

.input-part small {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.login {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  margin-top: -5px;
  font-size: 13px;
}
```

```html
<div class="signup">
  <div class="header">signup</div>

  <form action="signup.php" class="form" name="form01" method="post">

    <div class="input-part ">
      <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" placeholder="e.g Yusuf" required pattern="\w{2,100}" title="Please enter your name">
      <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
      <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
      <small>Error</small>
    </div>
    <div class="input-part">
      <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" placeholder="e.g Olanrewaju" required pattern="\w{2,100}" title="Please enter your name">
      <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
      <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
      <small>Error</small>
    </div>
    <div class="input-part">
      <label for="email">Email Address</label>
      <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="mail@email.com" required pattern="[a-z0-9._%+\-]+@[a-z0-9.\-]+\.[a-z]{2,}$" title="Please enter a valid email">
      <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
      <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
      <small>Error</small>
    </div>
    <div class="input-part">
      <label for="dob">Birthday</label>
      <input type="date" maxlength="10" id="dob" name="dob" placeholder="Enter your Birthday (YYYY/MM/DD)" title="Please enter your date of birth">
      <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
      <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
      <small id="dobError">Error</small>

      <script defer src="date.js"></script>

    </div>
    <div class="input-part">
      <label for="phone">Phone Number</label>
      <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Enter Phone Number" required pattern="\d{11}" title="Please enter your 11 digits number">
      <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
      <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
      <small>Error</small>
    </div>
    <div class="input-part">
      <label for="username">Username</label>
      <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Choose a Username" required pattern="\w{4,100}" title="Please choose a username">
      <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
      <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
      <small>Error</small>
    </div>
    <div class="input-part">
      <label for="password">Password</label>
      <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter a strong Password" required pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}" title="Please enter your password">
      <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
      <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
      <small id="passwordStrength">Error</small>
    </div>
    <div class="input-part">
      <label for="confpassword">Confirm Password</label>
      <input type="password" name="confpassword" id="confpassword" placeholder="Re-enter Password" required pattern="" title="Please repeate you password">
      <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
      <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
      <small>Error</small>
    </div>

    <button class="btn" type="submit">Signup</button>

  </form>

  <div class="login">
    <span>Have an account?</span> <a href="../index.html">Login</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The submit button is still not responding.

Comment: @Olalere I would like to help but you need to be more specific. In the snippet/example that I give the submit event will just result in a console log saying 'submit' -- is that the issue? You can just remove he first event lister.